# What is the best way to decouple one MVVM application into webservice and a client

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

What is the best way to decouple one MVVM application into webservice and a client.

The application is at an early age and is being developed with MVVM Light. recently born the need for business logic to a webservice so that it is available for a mobile client (Android, BB).

There is some "how to" or guide where I can guide me to do this correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MVVM pattern is a presentation pattern used on the client side. It shouldn't affect your system architecture. Usually, the view model is repsonsible for handling the behavior of the view. It is in the view model that you would want to interact with your services.

I would suggest you extract your business logic and make them your services which multiple clients can use, including your WPF client.

Comment: True, however, the view model will need to know when to pull changes from the model (even if affect by another VM). (Unless the changes aren't meant to be reflected automatically.)

Comment: Currently in my application I have: the view is simple XAML file, the ViewModel has CRUD logic and maintains the variables that populate the fields in the view, and last an intermediate model that encapsulates the logic of the actual model. how far should I go to the webservice